# Volley execute wrong method

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am using volley library to send data on server as a json. My server response successfully. Data is saving in database. But Volley execute the ErrorResponse, here is my code

```
  private  void  upload(final  Context context) {

    String url = BASE_URL + "upload.php";

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(ProfilePictureActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
         //   Log.i("Error", "" + error);

            Toast.makeText(context, "Cannot save", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> stringMap = new HashMap<>();


            stringMap.put("name", names);
            stringMap.put("date_of_birth",dobs);
            stringMap.put("address", presentAddress);
            stringMap.put("phone",phone);
            stringMap.put("email", email);
            stringMap.put("image",phone+".jpg");
            stringMap.put("photo",imageToString(bitmap));

            return stringMap;
        }
    };

    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: debug at first.

Comment: What HTTP status code does your server return?

Comment: What is the `int` result of `error.networkResponse.statusCode`?  This will be the HTTP status code, as per @AlgoRythm's question.